# C style struct with deleted default ctor quandary

Tags: c++

Say I have a C style struct as follows:

```
        typedef struct {
          const struct {
            int ac;
            int bc;
          } const_vars;
          int x;
          int y;
        } myCStruct;
```

I can initialize a variable of the above type as follows:

```
        myCStruct sVar = {{123,678},0,0};
```

Now I decide to have a `std::map` with the above:

```
        std::map<int,myCStruct,std::less<int>,myAllocator<std::pair<int,myCStruct>>> myMap;
```

Doing this I get a compilation error:

> error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'myCStruct'

`myMap` tried to instantiate myCStruct and ran up against a deleted default ctor. I understand the default ctor got deleted because of the `const` members of the struct. I tried changing the type to a C++ style struct, and defined a default ctor, but then I got stuck unable to initialize the variable `myCStruct sVar` as above, because the compiler couldn't find a matching ctor.

Q1. Would a matching ctor in this example take a `std::initializer_list`, `int`, and `int` as arguments?

Q2. This is a toy example, my actual use case is a bit more complex, and writing a matching ctor would be tedious (and seems like an overkill). I have more types like this, so I'll have to replicate this for all of them. The convenience of defining `myCStruct sVar` as shown above is unbeatable! Do I have an easy out?

Comment: Show the declaration of `myAllocator`.  If I use std::allocator, it compiles fine.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "C-style struct", in C++ this is what we call "a struct", where all that means is "all properties are public by default".

Comment: Yes, @tadman is right, there is no such thing as a C style struct. I was confused...